# TFS 2018 Board configuration - Columns option missing

Tags: tfs

I am trying to customize the Kanban board in TFS 2018 for new work item types I've added.

Following the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/kanban/add-columns , my configuration dialog seems to be missing the Board configuration.

Here's from the documentation
[image]

Here's my panel (I've added my user as the team administrator).
[image]

Any help in regards to customize my workflow and board is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the Kanban board settings are not available for the Sprint board. The settings page you're showing applies to backlogs such as Epics, Features and Backlog Items. Not to the Sprint backlog.

Comment: Is it not possible to customize the columns for a sprint board? How may I support the new task states I've added (Code Review / Test). Currently the task disappears when the task get's one of the new states.

Comment: When using VSTS to modify Task states, make sure that you map the new states to the In Progress category. That way they won't disappear from your board and the new columns will be added.

Comment: Can't find that in the Task.xml, under <WORKFLOW><STATES> and <TRANSITIONS>. Is it configured somewhere else?

Comment: Found it in the process configuration. Thanks again!